# How to disable the highlight of QTableView Delegate widget-type Editor after perform the openPersistentEditor

Tags: python, delegates, highlight, qtableview

I am developing a QTableView with ItemDelegate to display its specific widget Editor with openPersistentEditor. A pagination and filter mechanism been implemented with QSortFilterProxyModel, whenever there is a action of PageUp, PageDown or Filter changed, the program will close the previous rows of widget Editor and open new rows of widget Editor according to the "display_list" implemented.

The problem with current design is that the widget Editor will be **highlighted** after running the ***openPersistentEditor*** for each column cell in the display_list. I can not find a programmatic way to disable the highlighted cell.

I have tried the self.view.repaint(), self.view.update() without success. But manually bring forward/backward another window that the pyqt application MainWidonw refresh will disable the highlighted cells.

Following is the code segments of the TabWidget and CustomProxyModel been implemented.

Please note there is *open_editor()* and *close_editor()* in the class *MyTabController* will be triggered whenever there is a Page change action or a Filter action to be taken.

```
# PyQT5 and Filtering a Table Using Multiple Columns
# Refer to: https://www.onooks.com/pyqt5-and-filtering-a-table-using-multiple-columns/

import pandas as pd
from pandas_controller import *
from UI import MyTabWidget
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTableView, QMenu, QAction, QFileDialog
from datetime import datetime

DATE_FORMAT = "%Y-%m-%d"
# Ref: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strptime

page_record = 20
total_record = 0
last_page = 0
current_page = 0

model_total_record = 0
model_last_page = 0

display_list = []


def count_page_num(total_record, page_record):
    page_num = int(total_record / page_record)
    mod_num = total_record % page_record
    if mod_num == 0 and page_num > 0:
        page_num -= 1
        
    return page_num 

class MyTabController(MyTabWidget):

    def __init__(self, tab, schema_df, table_name):

        super().__init__()

        self.view = tab.view
        self.comboBox = tab.comboBox
        self.lineEdit = tab.lineEdit
        self.buttonImport = tab.buttonImport
        self.buttonExport = tab.buttonExport

        self.buttonPFirst = tab.buttonPFirst
        self.buttonPLast = tab.buttonPLast
        self.buttonPPrev = tab.buttonPPrev
        self.buttonPNext = tab.buttonPNext
        
        self.schema_df = schema_df[schema_df['Table'] == table_name]
        self.widget_list = list(self.schema_df.Widget)
        self.range_list = list(self.schema_df.Range)
        
        self.buttonImport.clicked.connect(self.import_file)

    # Event Handler

    def import_file(self):
    
        global page_record
        global total_record, model_total_record
        global last_page, model_last_page
    
        print ("import_file")
        self.filename, filetype = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open file", "../data")

        if len(self.filename) == 0:
            print ("Please select a file")
            return
            
        self.df = pd.read_excel(self.filename)
        self.df = self.df.fillna('None')
        
        self.header = self.df.columns.to_list()
        self.indexes = self.df.index.to_list()
        self.model = PandasModel(self.df, self.header, self.indexes)
        self.proxy = CustomProxyModel()   # Customized Filter
        self.proxy.setSourceModel(self.model)
        
        self.view.setModel(self.proxy)
        self.view.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
        self.view.setSelectionBehavior(QTableView.SelectRows)
        self.view.setWordWrap(True)
        self.view.resizeColumnsToContents()
        self.view.resizeRowsToContents()
        self.view.setShowGrid(True)
        self.view.isCornerButtonEnabled()
        
        #self.view.setItemDelegateForColumn(0,DateDelegate(self.view))

        self.view.setItemDelegate(Delegate(self.widget_list, self.range_list))
        
        self.comboBox.addItems(["{0}".format(col) for col in self.header])

        self.comboBox.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.on_comboBox_currentIndexChanged)
        self.lineEdit.textChanged.connect(self.on_lineEdit_textChanged)
        self.buttonExport.clicked.connect(self.export_file)

        self.buttonPFirst.clicked.connect(self.change_page)
        self.buttonPLast.clicked.connect(self.change_page)
        self.buttonPPrev.clicked.connect(self.change_page)
        self.buttonPNext.clicked.connect(self.change_page)

        self.horizontalHeader = self.view.horizontalHeader()
        self.horizontalHeader.sectionClicked.connect(self.on_view_horizontalHeader_sectionClicked)
        
        print ("test-1")

        total_record = self.model.rowCount()
        last_page = count_page_num(total_record, page_record)
        
        model_total_record = self.model.rowCount()
        model_last_page = count_page_num(total_record, page_record)
        
        print ("model_total_record:", model_total_record)
        print ("model_last_page:", model_last_page)
        
        self.proxy.setPage()
        self.open_editor()

        print ("test-2")

        print ("import_file completed")

        
    def export_file(self):
        output_path = '../output/'
        output_filename = output_path + self.filename
        df = pd.DataFrame(self.model._data, columns = self.header)
        df.to_excel(output_filename)
        #self.model._df.to_excel(output_filename)  

    def change_page(self):
    
        global page_record
        #global total_record
        global last_page
        global current_page
        
        button_name = self.sender().text()
        print("button clicked:", button_name)
        
        if button_name == "First":
            if current_page == 0:
                take_action = False
            else:
                new_page = 0
                take_action = True
        elif button_name == "Last":
            if current_page == last_page:
                take_action = False
            else:
                new_page = last_page
                take_action = True
        elif button_name == "Next":
            if current_page == last_page:
                take_action = False
            else:
                new_page = current_page + 1
                take_action = True
        elif button_name == "Prev":
            if current_page == 0:
                take_action = False
            else:
                take_action = True
                new_page = current_page - 1

        if take_action == True:
            print (current_page, new_page)
            prev_page = current_page
            current_page = new_page
            self.close_editor()
            self.proxy.setPage()    # Trigger the invalidateFilter()
            self.open_editor()
            #self.view.repaint()           # Refresh the Tab Widget


    def open_editor(self):
        global display_list
        
        for row in display_list:
            for column in range(self.model.columnCount()):
                index = self.proxy.index(row, column, QModelIndex())
                self.view.openPersistentEditor(index)

    def close_editor(self):
        global display_list
        
        for row in display_list:
            for column in range(self.model.columnCount()):
                index = self.proxy.index(row, column, QModelIndex())
                self.view.closePersistentEditor(index)
        

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def on_view_horizontalHeader_sectionClicked(self, logicalIndex):

        self.logicalIndex   = logicalIndex
        self.menuValues     = QMenu(self)
        self.signalMapper   = QtCore.QSignalMapper(self)
        self.comboBox.blockSignals(True)
        self.comboBox.setCurrentIndex(self.logicalIndex)
        self.comboBox.blockSignals(False)  # True

        #valuesUnique = self.model._df.iloc[:, self.logicalIndex].unique()
        value_list = [str(item[self.logicalIndex]) for item in self.model._data]
        valuesUnique = list(set(value_list))    # To get the unique value list
        #print (valuesUnique)
        
        actionAll = QAction("All", self)
        actionAll.triggered.connect(self.on_actionAll_triggered)
        self.menuValues.addAction(actionAll)
        self.menuValues.addSeparator()
        for actionNumber, actionName in enumerate(sorted(valuesUnique)):
            action = QAction(str(actionName), self)
            self.signalMapper.setMapping(action, actionNumber)
            action.triggered.connect(self.signalMapper.map)
            self.menuValues.addAction(action)
        self.signalMapper.mapped.connect(self.on_signalMapper_mapped)
        headerPos = self.view.mapToGlobal(self.horizontalHeader.pos())
        posY = headerPos.y() + self.horizontalHeader.height()
        posX = headerPos.x() + self.horizontalHeader.sectionPosition(self.logicalIndex)

        self.menuValues.exec_(QtCore.QPoint(posX, posY))

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_actionAll_triggered(self):
        self.close_editor()
        filterColumn = self.logicalIndex
        self.proxy.setFilter("", filterColumn)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        self.model.setFont(filterColumn, font)
        self.open_editor()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def on_signalMapper_mapped(self, i):
        self.close_editor()
        stringAction = self.signalMapper.mapping(i).text()
        filterColumn = self.logicalIndex
        self.proxy.setFilter(stringAction, filterColumn)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(True)
        self.model.setFont(filterColumn, font)
        self.open_editor()
        
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def on_lineEdit_textChanged(self, text):
        self.close_editor()
        self.proxy.setFilter(text, self.proxy.filterKeyColumn())
        self.open_editor()
        
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def on_comboBox_currentIndexChanged(self, index):
        self.close_editor()
        self.proxy.setFilterKeyColumn(index)
        self.open_editor()
        
class Delegate(QItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, widget_list, range_list):
        QItemDelegate.__init__(self)
        self.widget_list = widget_list
        self.range_list = range_list

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        column = index.column()
        widget = self.widget_list[column]
        range_list = self.range_list[column]
        #print ("createEditor:", column, widget)
        
        if widget == "QDateEdit":
            editor = QDateEdit(parent)
            editor.setCalendarPopup(True)
            return editor

        if widget == "QSpinBox":
            editor = QSpinBox(parent)
            editor.setMinimum(int(range_list[0]))
            editor.setMaximum(int(range_list[1]))
            return editor

        if widget == "QDoubleSpinBox":
            editor = QDoubleSpinBox(parent)            
            editor.setDecimals(3)
            editor.setMinimum(float(range_list[0]))
            editor.setMaximum(float(range_list[1]))
            #editor.setSingleStep(0.1)
            return editor

        if widget == "QComboBox":
            comboBox = QComboBox(parent)
            comboBox.addItems(range_list)
            return comboBox

        # no need to check for the other columns, as Qt automatically creates a
        # QLineEdit for string values and QTimeEdit for QTime values;
        return super().createEditor(parent, option, index)
        
        
    def setEditorData(self, editor, index):
        if isinstance(editor, QDateEdit):
            #dt_str = index.data(QtCore.Qt.EditRole)           
            dt_str = index.data(QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)  
            #print ("setEditorData, dt_str:", dt_str)
            dt = datetime.strptime(dt_str, DATE_FORMAT)
            editor.setDate(dt)
            return
        super().setEditorData(editor, index)
        
    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
        if isinstance(editor, QDateEdit):
            dt = editor.date().toPyDate()
            dt_str = dt.strftime(DATE_FORMAT)
            #print ("setModelData, dt_str:", dt_str)
            model.setData(index, dt_str, QtCore.Qt.EditRole)
            return
        super().setModelData(editor, model, index)

class CustomProxyModel(QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._filters = dict()

        self.fc = 0               # filter counter
        self.filter_flag = False
        self.filter_list = []
        
    @property
    def filters(self):
        return self._filters

    def setFilter(self, expresion, column):
        global total_record
        global last_page
        global model_total_record
        global model_last_page
        
        if expresion:
            self.filters[column] = expresion
        elif column in self.filters:
            del self.filters[column]

        if expresion:
            print ("setFilter invoke invalidateFilter()")
            total_record = model_total_record               # restore the original model total record
            last_page = model_last_page                     # restore the original model last page
            self.fc = 0                                     # reset filter counter
            self.filter_flag = True                         # Enabled to append the self.filter_list
            self.filter_list = []
            
            self.invalidateFilter()

            print ("filter counter:", self.fc)
            total_record = self.fc
            last_page = count_page_num(total_record, page_record)
            self.fc = 0
            self.filter_flag = False                         # Disabled to append the self.filter_list
        
        else:
            total_record = model_total_record
            last_page = model_last_page
            self.invalidateFilter()
            
    def setPage(self):

        self.invalidateFilter()
        
    def filterAcceptsRow(self, source_row, source_parent):
    
        global page_record
        global total_record
        #global last_page
        global current_page

        global display_list
        
        #print ("filterAcceptsRow:", source_row, source_parent)
        start_record = current_page * page_record
        end_record = start_record + page_record
        if end_record > total_record:
            end_record = total_record
        
        if len(self.filters.items()) == 0:    #None Filter Items
            # Filter by Current Page
            #print (source_row, start_record, end_record)
            if source_row < start_record:
                return False
            elif source_row >= end_record:
                return False        

        else:                                  # Filter Items
            for column, expresion in self.filters.items():
                text = self.sourceModel().index(source_row, column, source_parent).data()
                regex = QRegExp(
                    expresion, Qt.CaseInsensitive, QRegExp.RegExp
                )
                if regex.indexIn(text) == -1:
                    return False
            
                # Filter by Current Page
                #print ("Filter:", source_row, start_record, end_record)

                if self.filter_flag == True:
                    self.fc += 1                    
                    self.filter_list.append(source_row)
                
                    if self.fc < start_record:
                        return False
                    elif self.fc >= end_record:
                        return False
                else:
                    target_list = self.filter_list[start_record:end_record]
                    if source_row not in target_list:
                        return False

        display_list.append(source_row)

        return True
```

Tried self.view.repaint() and self.view.update() without success.

Comment: Hi You-Min, altering your code to have a complete [minimal-reproducible-example][1] would make it easier to quickly help debug your code. I don't have your custom libraries for 'pandas_controller' or your 'MyTabWidget' from  'UI' file to test.



  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks! There are six python files and two excel files in this mini system - start.py, UI.py, controller.py, pandas_controller.py, tab_controller.py, folium_controller.py, data.xlsx, schema.xlsx. The design is highly abstract so requires all these files to make it works. Let me think how it could be simplified and replicated.